# Maximum weight of a topology on $\{ 1 , 2 , 3 , \ldots , n \}$

Tags: general-topology, combinatorics

The *weight* of a topological space $X$ is the minimum cardinality of a basis for that space.

What is the maximum weight for a topology on $\{1,2,3,\ldots ,n\}$? Which topologies have that weight?

Comment: Hint: look at the power set.

Comment: Any thoughts on the matter?

Comment: What you call _magnitude_ is more commonly called [_weight_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_%28topology%29#Weight_and_character). I have edited your question to use this terminology.

Comment: @pedro, I think the discrete has maximum weight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Let $X=\{1,\ldots,n\}$, and let $\tau$ be a topology on $X$.

- Show that for each $x\in X$ there is a $B(x)\in\tau$ such that if $U$ is any $\tau$-open nbhd of $x$, then $B(x)\subseteq U$.
- Show that $\mathscr{B}=\{B(x):x\in X\}$ is a base for $\tau$, and that $w(\langle X,\tau\rangle)=|\mathscr{B}|$.

Comment: Thanks. I took $B(x)$ to be the intersection of all the open subsets containing $x$ (we can do it because there is a finite number of such subsets since the topology is finite)?
 Is this ok. Thank you

Comment: @TheEmperorofIceCream Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: @TheEmperorofIceCream: As Henno says, that's exactly the idea. When the underlying set is finite, each point has a smallest open nbhd.

Comment: How do we know that there is no smaller Basis for that topology than $\mathscr B$?

Comment: @СССР: Show that if $\mathscr{B}'$ is any base for $\tau$, then $\mathscr{B}\subseteq\mathscr{B}'$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott So suppose $\mathscr B$ and $\mathscr B'$ are both bases of $\underline X$. Take $B \in \mathscr B$. For some $x \in B \in T_{\underline X}$ it must hold that $\exists B' \in \mathscr B'$ with $x \in B' \subset B$. At the same time, due to the definition of $\mathscr B$ it holds that $B \subset B'$ because $B'$ is an open neighborhood of $x$. So $B = B'$, from which it follows that $B \in \mathscr B'$, more generally leading to $\mathscr B \subset \mathscr B'$.

Comment: @СССР: Yep, you’ve got it.